# Minify & Purge HTML/CSS/JSS

Tags: html, css, webpack, github-actions, esbuild

I use GitHub for source control my HTML, CSS and JS. I use Netlify / Cloudflare Pages to host my website (which is trigger off of a GitHub commit).

I work with static files (.html, .js and .css) and do not use programming frameworks like Ruby on Rails, Django, etc.

I’d like to create a GitHub Action that triggers on a git commit, to do the following:

a. Purge unused CSS.
b. Minify the HTML, CSS and JS
c. In-line the CSS & JS into the HTML file.

That way my site is minified, merged and purged of unused elements before it is automatically hosted by Netlify / Cloudflare Pages.

How would I go about doing this with GitHub Actions? I’ve looked into esbuild, webpack etc but all seem to come up short of being able to do all I need.

Comment: Netlify runs a build command for you automatically on push to the repo (after you have set it up to do so) , so you don't need anything else than a simple npm script for this in your package.json. I wrote about how I do it here: https://hgrid.io/documentation/production/ (you can add html and js compression to his same routine. See the package.json in the hgrid.io repo for ideas.

Comment: Ups, sorry missed the inline css part. It's maybe more involved so you might need a bundler for this. But everything that can be ran with a single build command on the server can fit into the process.

Comment: @anatolhiman thanks for the blog post. Do you have a version where you show all the final code combined.

Comment: It's basically just these scripts you need, see how I have done the same thing + compressing and uglification of JS here: https://github.com/ahansson/hgrid.io

Comment: And here you see how you configure the build command of your choice in Netlify, that runs all the individual build scripts in your package.json: https://www.netlify.com/products/build/

Answer (score 2):

My approach to this is a Github action that:

- checks out the `main` branch
- performs the minification/purging etc
- pushes the changes to a `build` branch

Then you just need to point Github Pages (or Netlify in your case) at the `build` branch rather than the `main` branch.

You'd need to choose appropriate CLI tools to perform the minifying/purging in the virtual machine that the action spins up. There are lots of options here. I'd suggest using packages that can be installed through `node` so that you only have to install that on the VM. For example:

- [PurgeCSS](https://purgecss.com/CLI.html): Removes unneeded CSS
- [terser](https://github.com/terser/terser): Minifies JS
- [csso-cli](https://github.com/css/csso-cli): Minifies CSS
- [html-minifier](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier): Minifies HTML

I'm not aware of any tools that you could use to inline your JS/CSS (and don't know why you'd want to), but I suspect they exist.

This is relatively straightforward with a Github action that looks a bit like this:

```yaml
# A Github Action that minifies html/css/js and pushes it to a new branch
name: purge-and-minify

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'main'

jobs:
  checkout-minify-push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      
      # Install CLI tools
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '16'
      - run: npm install -g terser
      - run: npm install -g csso-cli
      - run: npm install -g html-minifier

      # Use CLI tools to minify, overwriting existing files
      - run: for i in ./js/*.js; do terser $i --compress -o $i; done
      - run: for i in ./css/*.css; do csso $i -o $i; done
      - run: for i in ./html/*.html; do html-minifier [--your-options-here] $i -o $i; done
      
      # Push changes to `build` branch
      - run: |
          git config user.name github-username
          git config user.email github-username@user.noreply.github.com
          git commit -am 'Automated minify of ${{ github.sha }}'
          git push --force -u origin main:build
```